# how to keep selected option shown when back to settings page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage

i have a settings page with a gender drop down : male , female.
when i hit save settings i use local storage to save the selected option, but next time i go to the page it shows up male no matter what because its the first option. i want it to show the saved setting.

this is how i save it. not sure how to bring it back to check on settings page load

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="sel1">Gender:</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="gender">
      <option>Male</option>
      <option>Female</option>
   </select>
</div>

  (function (global) {
 document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function () {
 global.localStorage.setItem("mySharedData", document.getElementById("gender").value);
 }, false);
}(window));
```

Comment: use sessions to store the values..

Comment: You would need to retrieve the stored value and populate on `document.ready`

Comment: you are just storing it and not checking it and setting it again when you go back

Comment: @DevLakshman `localStorage` is there in the code.

Comment: any fix to the bottoms guys code? i cant get it to work and it should i believe

Answer (score 1):

You are saving the data, not retreiving it again

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="sel1">Gender:</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="gender">
      <option>Male</option>
      <option>Female</option>
   </select>
</div>

(function (global) {
    var data = global.localStorage.getItem("mySharedData"),
        sel = document.getElementById("gender"),
        opts = sel.options;

    if (data !== null) {
        for(var opt, j = 0; opt = opts[j]; j++) {
            if(opt.value == data) {
                sel.selectedIndex = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("save").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var val = document.getElementById("gender").value;
        global.localStorage.setItem("mySharedData", val);
    }, false);
}(window));
```

Comment: i plugged this in  just like u have it and it did nothing.

Comment: @bigdowg Sorry, made one small mistake.  Fixed now

Comment: it is still showing up Male when its outputting that has saved female =/ i cant figure it out either and its probably something small